# Is there a way to map the frame rate to keyframes?

Tags: animation, frame-rate

Is there a way to change the frame rate during an animation, using keyframes?

i wanna try making certain actions with different frame rates (close ups with 24fps while more action heavy shots take 12fps) without having to render the animation multiple times then stitching footage together or making a different project entirely.

Answer (score -1):

Wait i just realized i could just use the steps interpolation in the graph editor